# MySQL: Select max from group using the value from a different table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, and I'm trying to find the max value of a column in the first table grouped by a column in the second table.

Here's an example of what I mean:

table customers:

```
customer_id | age
12367       | 23
87693       | 48
66933       | 44
82143       | 38
75454       | 19
38912       | 58
63554       | 80
```

table purchases:

```
product_id | customer_id
132        | 12367
132        | 66933
132        | 38912
844        | 12367
844        | 63554
598        | 75454
598        | 87693
598        | 66933
```

I want to find the customer_id of the oldest purchaser of each product, e.g.:

```
product_id | customer_id | age
132        | 38912       | 58
844        | 63554       | 80
598        | 87693       | 48
```

How would I create an mysql query to find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use correlated subquery

```
select product_id , a.customer_id , age
from purchases a inner join customers b on a.customer_id =b.customer_id
where age in (select max(age) from purchases a1 inner join customers b1 on a1.customer_id =b1.customer_id where a.product_id=a1.product_id group by a1.product_id)
```